# .htaccess - Replace hyphen (dash) '-' with a foward slash '/'

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem with .htaccess

At this time I have something like this:

```
http://example.com/page-example?getVariable=1234
```

But I want something like:

```
http://example.com/page/example/1234
```

I tried to use that .htacces to replace the hyphens with slashes

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+).php/?$ /$1/$2 [R,L]
```

And I got something like this

```
 http://example.com/page/example?getVariable=1234
```

But the server can't find the path, I think it's because it admits that the 'page' is a folder.

How can I do what I want to, but the server search for the file 'page-example.php' at the root folder and not for 'example.php' at '/page/' ?

PS: I'm using already the code below to remove the .php extension and the 'www.' from the URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Do you mean `page-example.php?` ?  Also, I don't use rewrite often but aren't you doing the rewrite backwards?

Comment: I don't know that much about rewrite rules too, but what do you mean with backwards?

Comment: Your rewriterule was doing the actual path first instead of last but Jon Lin gave a pretty comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the rules that you already have, try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+page-([^/]+)(?:\.php|)\?getVariable=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /page-$1.php?getVariable=$2 [L,QSA]
```

So that the whole thing looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+page-([^/]+)(?:\.php|)\?getVariable=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /page-$1.php?getVariable=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: That's weird, it doesn't changed anything in the URL, stayed

    http://example.com/page-example?getVariable=1234

but thank you the same way for the help man!

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm! I don't know why it isn't  working at localhost (I have mod_rewrite active), I think it's because it has another path before all of it. It is "localhost/site/page/example", but in my website, going from de root folder, it worked perfectly!

Just another thing: Do you think that is a good friendly URL? 
I mean, "example.com/page/example/1234" instead of "example.com/page-example?getVariable=1234" ?